# Facebook API redirect_ui error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm implementing a new app that uses Facebook login:
On developers.facebook.com I set the Settings:
App Domains: (empty)
Site URL: http://localhost/site/
Client OAuth Login: Yes
Web OAuth Login: Yes
Force Web OAuth Reauthentication: No
Embedded Browser OAuth Login: No
Valid OAuth redirect URIs: http://localhost/site/externallogin/

And in my app the login link:

```
$facebook = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => FB_APP_ID,
  'app_secret' => FB_APP_SECRET,
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);

$helper = $facebook->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email', 'public_profile', 'user_friends'];
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl("http://localhost/site/externallogin", $permissions);
echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($loginUrl) . '">Log in with Facebook!</a><hr>';
```

And my externallogin page:

```
$helper = $facebook->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

But When I'm redirect I got the following error:

> Graph returned an error: Error validating verification code. Please
>   make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the
>   OAuth dialog request

I've tried to change default_graph_version to 2.2, change the Valid OAuth redirect URIs and the return url to all kinds, but nothing, the same.
I've read everything related with this and tried all the approach, but still the same.
I don't know what can be causing this error.

My question is: How can I fix this error I get the the access token correctly.
[print 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuJLa.png)
[print 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNBzM.png)

Comment: Stop randomly flailing around doing useless things like changing the `default_graph_version` setting. If you go to `http://localhost/site/externallogin` does your server automatically add a `/` on the end?

Comment: yes it adds the / in the end, when I type http://localhost/site/externallogin it will return http://localhost/site/externallogin/

Comment: That's your problem, then. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The page `$helper->getAccessToken()` runs on must be the **exact** same URL you provide to `$helper->getLoginUrl()`. As you've indicated `http://localhost/site/externallogin` redirects to `http://localhost/site/externallogin/` on your webserver, add the `/` when you make `$loginUrl`:

```
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl("http://localhost/site/externallogin/", $permissions);
```

Comment: I moved all the code getAccessToken the exact same URL as getLoginUrl. And I added the / to the end like: $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl("http://localhost/site/login/", $permissions); But I got the same error

Comment: @BrunoRamalho Please add to your question the exact output of `$helper->getLoginUrl()` and the exact URL of the page on your server that you get the error on.

Comment: the output of getLoginUrl() is `https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth?client_id=1569923779991238&state=fb7468d97be204df86afd437d175ce5f&response_type=code&sdk=php-sdk-5.1.2&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fsite%2Flogin%2F&scope=email%2Cpublic_profile%2Cuser_friends`

Comment: and the URL that I got the error: `http://localhost/site/login/?code=AQA6czFfNEXdaeDhwqTi4VswU2CSaTJftGnNX3j5uescwjY03s3eoUFYBjpAmTnsaOIeMzcyM-PlLlwmnhblwfWOa9wjR13iaqOqRvtXfGS2m66WKfwN8ZgI215RBlJMDO9LKMM-zHIGvpzzK0qRWpMLzRlcei8nfsLBu7vfXw2Z3ob7N0aOeXib5yCg_jzbabGKEhdM60ndaH55l1GIcMyzuEjtAbpLPbD30xDMNJGLBecP4OcmTvGb8OWYvZOaHBgMRVy14svhmoz5Ely99rCBxCJIIo5eNMP1DwktoO3ORB91-ohfY_TkCyXFElEqmAuyLUsFkw1lCE5tDi2_bFerRxeoQQMP8lgi-nZBh7peMw&state=9f6f322b141d8a099bc860f3795131e6#_=`

Comment: @BrunoRamalho If I go to your `getLoginUrl` URL it states `The redirect_uri URL is not supported`. Is `localhost` in your app's `App Domains` at https://developers.facebook.com/ in the settings?

Comment: @BrunoRamalho Can you provide a screenshot of https://developers.facebook.com/apps/1569923779991238/settings please?

Comment: Please see http://i.stack.imgur.com/yuJLa.png and http://i.stack.imgur.com/VNBzM.png

Comment: @BrunoRamalho Take a close look. You're getting the error on `http://localhost/site/login/` but you've set the valid OAuth URLs in the second screenshot to `http://localhost/site/externallogin/`.

Comment: because now I changed everything to login page. I already tried exactly as it is with externallogin